# Failed to start Load Kernel Modules after Nvidia 352.21 installation failure

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel

After booting up Ubuntu 15.04 I get the following message:

```
 [FAILED] Failed to start Load Kernel Modules.
See "systemctl status systemd-modules-load.service" for details.
```

At terminal I get the following:

```
 renzo@renzo-lenovo-z50-70:~$ systemctl status systemd-modules-load.service -l
● systemd-modules-load.service - Load Kernel Modules
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-modules-load.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since mié 2015-06-17 17:57:35 PET; 49min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-modules-load.service(8)
           man:modules-load.d(5)
  Process: 420 ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd-modules-load (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 420 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

jun 17 17:57:35 renzo-lenovo-z50-70 systemd-modules-load[420]: Module 'fuse' is builtin
jun 17 17:57:35 renzo-lenovo-z50-70 systemd-modules-load[420]: could not find module by name='off'
jun 17 17:57:35 renzo-lenovo-z50-70 systemd-modules-load[420]: Failed to insert 'off': Function not implemented
jun 17 17:57:35 renzo-lenovo-z50-70 systemd-modules-load[420]: could not find module by name='off'
jun 17 17:57:35 renzo-lenovo-z50-70 systemd-modules-load[420]: Failed to insert 'off': Function not implemented
jun 17 17:57:35 renzo-lenovo-z50-70 systemd-modules-load[420]: could not find module by name='off'
jun 17 17:57:35 renzo-lenovo-z50-70 systemd[1]: systemd-modules-load.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
jun 17 17:57:35 renzo-lenovo-z50-70 systemd[1]: Failed to start Load Kernel Modules.
jun 17 17:57:35 renzo-lenovo-z50-70 systemd[1]: Unit systemd-modules-load.service entered failed state.
jun 17 17:57:35 renzo-lenovo-z50-70 systemd[1]: systemd-modules-load.service failed.
renzo@renzo-lenovo-z50-70:~$
```

I've already tried to reinstall kernel modules using synaptic but Im not sure how to interpretate what I have copied above.

Comment: it seems like the same [problem](http://askubuntu.com/questions/689320/failed-to-load-modules-at-startup-could-not-find-module-by-name-off?noredirect=1#comment1005856_689320) I just solved for 15.10.